# How to do the latex code for the following op amp circuits?

Tags: circuitikz, opamp

[image: Op Amp Diagram]

I am unsure about how to code op amp circuits. Can someone please help me code this ASAP ?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Welcome.There is a whole example with a very similar circuit in the manual: https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsection.2.2

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want. You can stretch out the whole thing simply by changing the numbers here and there.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
    node[op amp](amp){}
    (amp.out)
      to[short,-*] ++(0.5,0)coordinate(out)
      to[short,-o] ++(1,0) node[right]{$V_{\mathrm{o}}$}
    (amp.-)
      to[short,bipole nodes={none}{circ,color=blue}]
        ++(-.5,0)coordinate(A)node[below,blue]{$A$}
      to[short] ++(0,1) coordinate(tmp)
      to[R,l=$R_y$] (tmp-|out)
      to[short] (out)
    (amp.+)
      to[short] (amp.+-|A)
      to[vsource,l_=$V_{\mathrm{i}}$] ++(0,-1.5) node[sground](gnd){}
    (A)
      to[R,l_=$R_x$] ++(-2.5,0)coordinate(tmp)
      to[short] (tmp|-gnd) node[sground]{}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]